# How to split text to a row using appscript?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I made a daily student attendance app using Kodular and a spreadsheet as a database. I connected the kodular to a spreadsheet using Appscript. The app worked well, but since I'm a newbie in app script I can only send the data to a spreadsheet as shown below
[image: output from the attendance app]

I need help splitting the text using commas as delimiters into a row. Here's my expectation:
[image]

here's the function I use to call the data from the app, I'm still a newbie and I just know basic functions like this

```
function doPost(e) {
return ceksheet(e);
}

function ceksheet(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH); 

//CREATE
if (e.parameter.func == "Create") {
  var ts = e.parameter.TIMESTAMP;
  var user = e.parameter.USER;
  var tgl = e.parameter.TANGGAL;
  var kls = e.parameter.KELAS;
  var nama = e.parameter.NAMA;
  var ket = e.parameter.KETERANGAN;
  var data = false;
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var data_ts = sh.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if(data_ts==ts){
      data=true;
    } 
  }
  if (data){
    var result= "ID Sudah ada";
  }else{
    var rowData = sh.appendRow([ts,user,tgl,kls,nama,ket]);  
    var result="Berhasil Input";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

FYI, here's the image of the app
[image: attendance app]
As you can see in the blue box, I intended to compile the data as one label per component ( timestamp in one label, name in one label, etc) as I planned to split it using appscript, It's just not resolved yet.
Kindly need your help to resolve this problem...

Comment: Please [edit] to include your existing code so far.  As it stands it isn't clear what you are having a problem with. Please review [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [site tour](/tour).

Comment: Is this question closed or reopened? can someone still answer my question? I am sorry since I new in this community, still confuse but I still need an answer :(

Comment: Thanks for updating.  This looks to be a better fit at [so]. I'll migrate it over.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do. There are different pieces. It is best to simplify to sonething like: "I get this `[example]`, but I want want `[desired example]`". Is the problem with the data or the apps script or getting it into sheets? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) More clarity will make it easier for others to engage and help you.

Comment: Can you add an example of the data the app sends to `doPost`?

Answer (score 0):

To split those comma-delimited values into rows, and build a 2D array of the results, use `Array.forEach()`, like this:

```js
function ceksheet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.func !== 'Create') return;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH);
  if (!sheet) throw new Error(`Cannot find sheet '${e.parameter.SH}'.`);
  let result = 'ID Sudah ada';
  const keys = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat();
  if (!keys.includes(e.parameter.TIMESTAMP)) {
    const rowData = [];
    ['TIMESTAMP', 'USER', 'TANGGAL', 'KELAS', 'NAMA', 'KETERANGAN',]
      .map(field => e.parameter[field])
      .forEach((delimited, columnIndex) =>
        String(delimited).split(',')
          .forEach((value, rowIndex) => {
            if (!rowData[rowIndex]) rowData[rowIndex] = [];
            rowData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;
          })
      );
    rowData.forEach(row => sheet.appendRow(row));
    result = 'Berhasil Input';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

See [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your showing script, I remember [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78183771). When the answer in this thread is used, your script becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  return ceksheet(e);
}

function ceksheet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH);
  if (e.parameter.func == "Create") {
    var ts = e.parameter.TIMESTAMP;
    var user = e.parameter.USER;
    var tgl = e.parameter.TANGGAL;
    var kls = e.parameter.KELAS;
    var nama = e.parameter.NAMA;
    var ket = e.parameter.KETERANGAN;

    // --- I modified the below script.
    var lr = sh.getLastRow();
    var temp = [ts, user, tgl, kls, nama, ket].map(c => c.split(",").map(d => d.trim()));
    var maxLen = Math.max(...temp.map(e => e.length));
    temp = temp.map(e => e.length < maxLen ? [...e, Array(maxLen - e.length).fill(null)] : e);
    var values = temp[0].map((_, col) => temp.map((row) => row[col] || null));
    var result = "ID Sudah ada";
    if (!sh.getRange("A2:A" + lr).createTextFinder(values[0][0]).findNext()) {
      sh.getRange(lr + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      result = "Berhasil Input";
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```

- In this modification, from your showing sample image and your for loop, I suppose that all values `TIMESTAMP` in a cell of column "A" are the same timestamp. And, in order to check the duplicate values from column "A", I used TextFinder. In this case, even when one of the timestamps is used, it can be searched from a single cell with multiple values.
- If you want to search the value of column "A" as one value in a cell, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      if (!sh.getRange("A2:A" + lr).createTextFinder(values[0][0]).findNext()) {
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (!sh.getRange("A2:A" + lr).createTextFinder(values[0][0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext()) {
    ```
- By the way, in your script, when `e.parameter.func == "Create"` is false, no value is returned. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".