# How to split multiline text to rows using app script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use a 3rd APP with spreadsheet as database. Each time the app executed, it will return data as multiline text shown below:
| Code | Name | Date | Task | Unit | progress |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|code1
code2
code3|user1
user2
user3|date1
date2
date3|task1
task2
task3|unit1
unit2
unit3|done
ongoing
need revision|
(PS: I saw my first column was mess after I post it, so I give this image of the data returned from the app, just in case the table not load properly)
[multiline text table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD0cC.png)

I need to split the multiline data in to rows using app script, so it should look like this,

| Code | Name | Date | Task | Unit | progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | user1 | date1 | task1 | unit1 | done |
| code2 | user2 | date2 | task2 | unit2 | ongoing |
| code3 | user3 | date3 | task3 | unit3 | need revision |

I know simple script like how to split text to columns using delimiter, for example like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lr= sh.getLastRow();
  var range1= sh.getRange('A2:A' + lr);
  range1.splitTextToColumns('\n');

}
```

But it's just split the the text to columns, not to the row below, and obviously it won't not work for the array of data. How can I split multiline text to rows using app script?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // --- I modified the below script.
  var values = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var newValues = values.flatMap(r => {
    var temp = r.map(c => c.split("\n").map(d => d.trim()));
    var maxLen = Math.max(...temp.map(e => e.length));
    temp = temp.map(e => e.length < maxLen ? [...e, Array(maxLen - e.length).fill(null)] : e);
    return temp[0].map((_, col) => temp.map((row) => row[col] || null));
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length).clearContent().setValues(newValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run with your provided sample table, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)